# Possible to use FPGA to emulate TTL logic ICs in existing circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, logic-gates

Is it possible to use an FPGA to emulate and 'replace' a damaged 7 series logic chip on an existing circuit board?

For example, if I have a VCR or receiver that has a damaged 7 series logic IC, is it possible to remove the damaged chip, emulate its logic on my Cyclone IV, then connect my FPGA's pins to the pins on the PCB and have a working device again?

I would like to know if this is possible despite its impracticability. Hypothetical scenario, I would like to know if this is possible if you wanted. Google hasn't turned up any relevant information

Comment: That would be a really expensive "fix". You need the FPGA to have the same logical voltage levels at the very least.

Comment: Cheaper by far to look up a modern equivalent for your 74XX series part.

Comment: "Is it possible" questions are not well suited to this site. It's unlikely that anyone can prove that it is **not** possible, so the best we can say is....maybe.

Comment: I think you should tell us which logic chip you are trying to replace. Note that CPLDs are more like logic gates then FPGAs.

Comment: One timing consideration is that most FPGA require some time at power up to configure, so if the target circuit requires operation immediately when power is applied with no delay, an FPGA will not work in that case. On the other hand a PLA or CPLD should start up right away.

Answer (score 3):

In theory: definitely yes.
In practice: Yes, in some cases, but you won't use a Cyclone IV for this.

First, you have to make sure that the FPGA is electrically compatible with the board. That is, you must be able to set its I/O voltage to the voltage required by the board.
Then, the driving strength has to match - FPGA usually don't deliver more than 12 mA per pin, while many 74xx chips offer a lot more. 
Then, the I/O type has to match - is the broken 74xx TTL or CMOS? Does it have a push-pull output stage or e.g. an open drain output? Does it have pull resistors or a hysteresis on the inputs?
What are the requirements for propagation delays of the chip? Rise time of signals?

For common chips you will be able to find the necessary settings in an FPGA, but for special ones it will be impossible. Given that you have an FPGA that can deliver the required electrical performance, the huge drawback of large FPGA like your Cyclone IV is that they need a large amount of external components (Flash, voltage regulators...) and that is very impractical to provide "just" to replace a 74xx chip.

On the other hand, there are several tiny FPGA on the market that only need a single supply voltage and no further external components. Examples are the ice and MachXO series from Lattice, sizes start at around 3x3mm² and prices are about 1 $€£. So, you might actually be able to fit one into the socket of the original broken 74xx chip.

Summarizing: Yes, it might work, but it's an awful lot of work and not a viable way to go in most cases.

Some examples of what can not be done with FPGA:

- All legacy 7400 from the original series can not be emulated without external level shifters, because they use 5V I/O not provided by any current FPGA
- Some 74xx series, like 74CBTLVxx offer very fast propagation delays of less than 2 ns. This is faster than most FPGA that have a pin-to-pin delay of several nanoseconds.
- There are devices like 74xx19 with a Schmitt-triggered input. These have a large hysteresis that can't be provided in FPGA without external components.
- There are devices like 74xx06 with an high-voltage open-collector output, far beyond the capabilities of an FPGA.
- There are analog chips like 74xx624 that is an voltage controlled oscillator - that's outside the domain of what an FPGA can do.
- There are high-current bi-directional analog multiplexers (e.g. 74CBTLV3257) - you could replace these with some transistors, but not with an FPGA.

Comment: Multiple FPGA pins can be driven at the same time to increase drive current as necessary. The Cyclone IV that the OP specified has 3.3V I/O which is probably compatible with TTL levels. You said "for special ones it will be impossible"...can you give an example of a 74XX TTL chip that can not be emulated with the Cyclone IV? I'm not doubting your word, but a specific example would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

FPGA is overkill for this work, take a look at cheap CPLDs like X9572XL. You can do a lot of things with this, and talking about replace 74xx series chips, Xilinx has an interesting document:
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp202.pdf

datasheet (3.3v supply, 5v tolerant in, 3v3 out): https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds057.pdf

If you're interested, Ali has lots of cheap dev boards, configuration tools and chips to test with it.

The drawback of this for me is the need to configure it. may be ok if it is only a replacement and hobby, but for a mass production device you need to take care of the default state of the pins when not configured (to avoid problems with the rest of the circuit) and also take into account the configuration costs in factory or in your time.

Comment: Modern, low-end FPGA are cheaper, much more capable of different I/O types, have lower power consumption, more features and are equally simple to program.

Comment: What FPGA's are you referring to? Some lattice?

Comment: E.g. Lattice iCE40UL-640.
The more capable MachXO3 series starts at around 2€

Comment: great device! thanks for the point